# Node.js express app.get() odd behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a question about `app.get()` in Express. The function does not seem to be called whenever the path has `.html` at the end of it. In the snippet below, `"test"` is written to the console if I try to go to `/random/example`, but not when I go to `/index.html`. So how do I make it call the function when I go to the homepage? (I've tried with '/' as the path and it doesn't work either.)

```
app.use(express.static("public"))

app.get('/index.html',function(req,res){
   console.log("test");
})

app.get('/random/example',function(req,res){
   console.log("test");
})
```

Comment: Did you define `app.static` somewhere?

Comment: I've converted the Stack Snippet in your question into just a code block. Stack Snippets are for examples than can be run in the snippet window (e.g., on the browser). Code that only works server-side shouldn't go in a Stack Snippet.

Comment: maybe your index.html (like most of the static resources used to) is cached in the browser and then not explicitly requested from the server

Comment: Check this: [Serving static files in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: I did not define app.static, do I have to do that?

Comment: @Torstein97: *"I did not define app.static, do I have to do that?"* No, only if you want to use static file serving. (Which is a frequent thing to want to do, but you don't need it for the above.)

Comment: It turns out I did define app.static (I believe). Without that line it works, but it doesn't actually load the page. When I add app.use(express.static("public")) then it loads the page but doesn't write "test" to the console.

Comment: I doesn't work (`console.log()`) because your requesting a static file and not a route.

Comment: How do I request a route instead of a static file?

Comment: If you have an index.html file within your `public` static assets folder then you dont need to declare a route for it to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't see the `"test"` for `/index.html` because that process is being handled for you by the static file handling.

If you want to have your code called **and** have the static handling, you need to define your route prior to setting up static handling. Your route is then effectively middleware, and can do processing before calling `next` to pass on to the next layer of handling, which will be the static handling:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// Set this up first
app.get('/index.html',function(req,res, next){
   console.log("test - /index.html");
   next(); // <== Let next handler (in our case, static) handle it
});

app.get('/random/example',function(req,res){
   console.log("test /random/example");
});

// Now define static handling
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
});
```

This is mentioned in [`get`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.get) with a link to [*Middleware callback function examples*](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#middleware-callback-function-examples).

**Note:** You don't need to do that if you just want `index.html` to be delivered to the browser. You only need to do it if you want to hook into the request before handing it off to static file handling.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.